# CacheHelper generic

Tags: c#

I came across a problem which for me is a bit tricky..
I have a Cache helper class that is generic..s...
I'm thinking of removing the casting just before the if statement and cast the object when returning it at the end...?

Comment: I'd suggest that caching null is probably never useful. Even if the value you want to cache is null, wrapping it with a container class that isn't null seems better. How can your client tell the difference between "that item has no cache data" and "the cached data is null"? And how can you tell this when reviewing logs or maybe even stepping through code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're concerned that the obj variable can be null after function.Invoke() then you can test and use the default operator.

```
public static class CacheHelper<T>
{
    public static T Get(string key, Func<T> function) {
        var obj = HttpContext.Current.Cache[key]; // removed the cast
        if (obj == null)
        {
            obj = function.Invoke();

            if (obj == null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(key, obj, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3), TimeSpan.Zero, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        }

        return (T)obj; // now obj won't be null, but it might still be a different type
    }
}
```